# convert xml data as String

Tags: java, xml, converters

I am passing xml data as input and want my java code to read it as a single line string .
I could achieve it as a single line,but the problem is in conversion of this line.
"?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?"
I could do it by using \" but I want my java code to handle  this data and convert it to a String by escaping the quotes(").

Comment: Are you talking about copy/pasting an xml file into your java source?

Comment: Escaping characters is done for the java compiler. The escape doesn't exist at runtime in the string.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find more in details from http://www.journaldev.com/1237/java-convert-string-to-xml-document-and-xml-document-to-string